# huge matrix sorted and then find smallest elements with their indices into a list

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I have a matrix `M` that is rather large. I am trying to find the top 5 closest distances along with their indices.

```
M = csr_matrix(M)
dst = pairwise_distances(M,Y=None,metric='euclidean')
```

`dst` becomes a huge matrix and I am trying to sort it efficiently or use scipy or sklearn to find the closest 5 distances.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
X = np.array([[2, 3, 5], [2, 3, 6], [2, 3, 8], [2, 3, 3], [2, 3, 4]])
```

I then calculate `dst` as:

```
[[ 0.  1.  3.  2.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  2.  3.  2.]
 [ 3.  2.  0.  5.  4.]
 [ 2.  3.  5.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  2.  4.  1.  0.]]
```

So, row 0 to itself has a distance of `0.`, row 0 to 1 has a distance of `1.`,... row 2 to row 3 has a distance of `5.`, and so on. I want to find these closest 5 distances and put them in a list with the corresponding rows, maybe like *[distance, row, row]*. I don't want any diagonal elements or duplicate elements so I take the upper triangular matrix as follows:

```
[[ inf   1.   3.   2.   1.]
 [ nan  inf   2.   3.   2.]
 [ nan  nan  inf   5.   4.]
 [ nan  nan  nan  inf   1.]
 [ nan  nan  nan  nan  inf]]
```

Now, the top 5 distances least to greatest are:

```
[1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 4], [1, 3, 4], [2, 1, 2], [2, 0, 3], [2, 1, 4]
```

As you can see there are three elements that have distance `2` and three elements that have distance `1`. From these I want to randomly choose one of the elements with distance `2` to keep as I only want the top *f* elements where *f*=5 in this case.

This is just a sample as this matrix could be very large. Is there an efficient way to do the above besides using a basic sorted function? I couldn't find any sklearn or scipy to help me with this.

Comment: You should have a look at [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/)

Comment: looks great, i'll check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fully vectorized solution to your problem:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

def smallest(M, f):
    # compute the condensed distance matrix
    dst = pdist(M, 'euclidean')
    # indices of the upper triangular matrix
    rows, cols = np.triu_indices(M.shape[0], k=1)
    # indices of the f smallest distances
    idx = np.argsort(dst)[:f]
    # gather results in the specified format: distance, row, column
    return np.vstack((dst[idx], rows[idx], cols[idx])).T
```

Notice that `np.argsort(dst)[:f]` yields the indices of the smallest `f` elements of the condensed distance matrix `dst` sorted in ascending order.

The following demo reproduces the result of your toy example and shows how the function `smallest` deals with a fairly large matrix of [image: 10000*2000] integers:

```
In [59]: X = np.array([[2, 3, 5], [2, 3, 6], [2, 3, 8], [2, 3, 3], [2, 3, 4]])

In [60]: smallest(X, 5)
Out[60]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  4.],
       [ 1.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 2.,  0.,  3.],
       [ 2.,  1.,  2.]])

In [61]: large_X = np.random.randint(100, size=(10000, 2000))

In [62]: large_X
Out[62]: 
array([[ 8, 78, 97, ..., 23, 93, 90],
       [42,  2, 21, ..., 68, 45, 62],
       [28, 45, 30, ...,  0, 75, 48],
       ..., 
       [26, 88, 78, ...,  0, 88, 43],
       [91, 53, 94, ..., 85, 44, 37],
       [39,  8, 10, ..., 46, 15, 67]])

In [63]: %time smallest(large_X, 5)
Wall time: 1min 32s
Out[63]: 
array([[ 1676.12529365,  4815.        ,  5863.        ],
       [ 1692.97253374,  1628.        ,  2950.        ],
       [ 1693.558384  ,  5742.        ,  8240.        ],
       [ 1695.86408654,  2140.        ,  6969.        ],
       [ 1696.68853948,  5477.        ,  6641.        ]])
```

Comment: How fast would this be for a matrix like 10000 x 2000?

Comment: Also, there can be duplicate values there just can't be any values from a diagonal like index (1,1),(0,0),(n,n). But this seems to only include unique values. I just want the f smallest distances that are not row,col (n,n)

Comment: "Notice that np.unique(dst)[:f] yields the smallest f distances from dst sorted in ascending order without any duplicate values." 

I can't figure out how to efficiently yield the smallest f distances from dat sorted in ascending order. There can be no values but none from row,col (n,n) thought if that makes sense

Comment: That's really fast, I really want to use this if I can get that one part working

Comment: Just did! I am concerned with this line

top_f = np.unique(dst)[:f]

I have been trying to find a way to keep these elements not necessarily remove all duplicates because if I have 4 minimum elements and 3 are zeros then I want to keep all 3 indices with zeros and then add the 4th and final element to the list with its value

Comment: If I use top_f = np.unique(dst)[:f] with this case X = np.array([[2,3,5],[2,3,6],[2,3,8],[2,3,3],[2,3,4]]) I get the wrong solution. It finds the correct minimum values but returns the wong indices with wrong distances